# Upgrade 13.10 to 14.04 problems

Tags: upgrade

Upgrade manager won't allow updates to 13.10 nor upgrade to 14.04.  It thinks I still have 13.04.
Have 64-bit dual-boot Win 8.1 / Ubuntu 13.10.  The U-13.10 upgraded online from 13.04 in October.  All updates run.  Now U/manager wants me to go from 13.04 to 13.10 first, ok I'll play, it starts then says I have all updates, won't go forward.  I've tried both Update/Upgrade Manager and command line.  Nothing works.  About Computer reports 13.10 but tell that to U/Manager.

I have the latest .iso but then I'd have to re-format and I would lose my local settings/data.  What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Command

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

I followed this tutorial an it worked

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04